# Facebook sdk Unity open graph action does not display

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-opengraph, facebook-unity-sdk

So, I am trying to implement the facebook open graph posts in our game for highscores, but it doesn't seem to post anything. When I do this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string,string>() { {"highscore", "http://samples.ogp.me/111111111111111"}};
FB.API("me/namespace:get_a_new", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, HandleOpenGraphCallback, data);
```

When I log the FBResult.text in the HandleOpenGraphCallback callback, I get a valid json response looking like this: `{"id":"422166374597399"}`. But the problem is that I see nothing on the test account that sent that request. The request obviously kind of worked since I receive an id in my callback function, but I see no post. Do I need to put more information in my dictionary in order to even see the post in the my test account timeline? I also put the "publish_action" permission in my login to be sure.

Thank you.